# Is there an easy way to zoom two plot widgets at once?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqtgraph

I am currently working on a graphical display tool for EEG data. My group wants to be able to zoom the plot to see certain channels. However, there is a separate widget beside the waveform plot which displays the labels for the channels.

I want to make it so that when the waveform plot is zoomed (say using ViewBox's RectMode zoom), the channel labels will also zoom. I have included a picture of our display for reference.

[image: Default display]

Comment: What library are you using for plotting? If your widget exposes a "limits-changed" event or similar you could connect to that and change the limits of the other plot accordingly.

Comment: We are using the PlotWidget from pytqtgraph to plot the data. Do you have an idea of how to access this sort of method for pyqtgraph objects?